# About the critical strip

Tags: reference-request, riemann-zeta, zeta-functions

My question is about the definition of the critical strip: 
Some authors (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CriticalStrip.html) consider it as the set of complex numbers $z=x+iy$ with $0<x<1$ and others consider it with the condition $0≤x≤1$ (http://planetmath.org/criticalstrip). Some authors calimed that the Riemann hypothesis is false for the eta function $∑_{n=1}^{∞}(-1)ⁿ⁺¹/n^{z}$ since it have zeros of the form $1+iv$. Some others claimed that the zeta and the eta functions has the same nontrivial zeros on the critical strip and hence the RH is true for the eta function.

How one can understant all these contradictions.

Comment: Always better to be specific, rather than saying "some."

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Ok removed.

Comment: @E.J RH is not known to be true for the zeta function, so if zeta and eta had the same zeros, it would be an open question for eta, not true for eta.

Comment: @StellaBiderman: All my concern is about the definition of the critical strip.

Comment: @E.J You said something that isn't true so I'm correct it. I know it's not the focus of the question which is why this is a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: @E.J The answer is in your question : it is a matter of definition.

Comment: Also see the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selberg_class $\eta(s)$ not being in it because of the growth of the coefficients $b_n$ of its logarithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Serre has work exhibiting zero-free regions in the critical strip.  These are open regions containing the axes $x=0$ and $x=1$ though they get narrower and narrower for large $y$.  At any rate this shows that there are no zeros on the two axes and therefore it is immaterial whether the critical strip is defined by $<$ or $\leq$.